# How to delete a value with specific name in registry using powershell?

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to loop over a registry key and delete all values starting with name OPEN.
This is for cleaning up OPEN keys in Excel.

[image: registry values]

```
get-itemproperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
```

Will list all the values like a key/value pair below.

```
FirstRun                   : 0
DDECleaned                 : 1
Options5                   : 128
OptionFormat               : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
Pos                        : 78,78,1440,759
MonitorTopologyFingerprint : 17560084649696315692
MsoTbCust                  : 8
ShowLensTooltip            : 0
Maximized                  : 2
MRUFuncs                   : 4,6,5,1,359,0,7,15,345,59
StickyPtX                  : 712
StickyPtY                  : 418
FormulaBarExpandedLines    : 11
FormulaBarExpanded         : 0
DefaultSheetR2L            : 0
UseSystemSeparators        : 1
ThousandsSeparator         : ,
DecimalSeparator           : .
Options                    : 87
ShowCSVDataLossWarning     : 0
DefaultURLPath             : C:\Users\UReddy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\URL\
OPEN                       : /R "C:\Users\adminuser\Downloads\PAforExcel.xll"
PSPath                     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel
                             \Options
PSParentPath               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel
PSChildName                : Options
PSDrive                    : HKCU
PSProvider                 : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Can access these individual values using the first field.

```
(get-itemproperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options).FirstRun
0
(get-itemproperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options).Pos
78,78,1440,759
```

Can anyone please suggest how to delete all values with Name field is starting with **OPEN**.

Say like OPEN,OPEN1,OPEN2,etc

Comment: `Remove-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options' -Name OPEN*`

Answer (score 0):

Got this.

Corrections are welcome

```
Function DeleteOpenKeys()
{
    $sReg="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options"
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    Log ""
    Log "Deleting open keys in registry '$sReg'"
    $sKey = Split-Path $sReg
    $aKey = $sKey.Split("\")
    If (!($aKey[0].EndsWith(":"))) {$aKey[0]=$aKey[0] + ":"}
    $sKey = $aKey -Join "\"
    $sName = Split-Path $sReg -leaf

    $sKey = "$sKey\$sName"
    $allValues = get-itemproperty $sKey
     $allValues.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -like 'OP*'){
      Remove-ItemProperty "$sKey" -Name $_.Name
    }
    }

}
```